# running Blender and Cycles on AWS spot instances

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Anyone have advice for running long and heavy Blender processes on AWS EC2 spot instances? Specifically, I'd like to know if Cycles renders and scene construction operations can be dumped to disk, even if they're only partially complete, then restarted on another instance.

I'm building very large scenes containing tens of thousands of copied geometric primitives. Then I'm rendering very large single frames of those scenes using Cycles. Building the scenes takes 6-8 hours, even after optimizing with copying and deferred linking. Renders take 12-18 hours for a single frame. Both time estimates are from a 2020 Apple MBP laptop: 2.6 GHz with 16 GB RAM.

My understanding of AWS EC2 is that spot instance jobs are given 2 minutes to quit and make the processors available to full-price-paying customers. Is there any persistent data I can dump from my scene builds and renders that I can save and restart from on a new spot instance? Does Blender support workflows that start from whereever they last left off?

If not, can Cycles render tiles be defined on the command-line? Assuming that's possible, I could setup a large number of small render jobs, the loss of any one of which could be made up without too much extra compute.

Thanks in advance!
scofra